# How to I get the table row ID and display it using echo?

Tags: php

*If I input a number then click increase or decrease stock, it should display the row ID and the input stock value.*

*The problem is how to I get the row ID and display it?*

[image: picture]

*The Item Management ID is __ and you input 10 stock*

*The blank is suppose to display the row ID*

*My code:*

```
      $stock = <<<DELIMETER
  <form action="" method="post">
  <td>
  <input type="number" name="stock">
  <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="add_stock" value="Increase Stock">
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="minus_stock" value="Decrease Stock">
  </td>
  </form>
  DELIMETER;
  echo $stock;
  echo "<td><a href ='edit.php?edit={$item_management_id}'>Edit</a>
  <a href='inventory_management.php?delete={$item_management_id}'>Delete</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

if(isset($_POST['add_stock'])) {
  $stock = $_POST['stock'];
  //$query = "SELECT * FROM item_management WHERE item_management_id = {$the_item_management_id}";
  echo "The Item Management ID is __ and you input $stock stock";}
```

Comment: Put the item ID in a hidden field in the form, and then you can retrieve it from $_POST just like the stock value

Comment: @ADyson thank you very much for your answer I able to solve my problem!